# AWS Autoscaling/EC2 billing increments?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

When I use AWS autoscaling to launch instances, am I being charged for the full hour *every time* I launch an instance?

Lets say my auto scaling is being triggered every 20 minutes, followed by launching 6 instances that runs a job that takes 10 minutes to execute, and then the instances terminate.  So in an hour range I will be launching 18 machines in total.

Will I be charged for 18 hours, or 180 minutes (18 * 10 minute to execute)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: **yes**.

With Amazon EC2, you pay for each **instance-hour** and is *rounded up*. So for example:

- An instance is created at 12:01 and is terminated at 14:32. This equals 2 hours and 31 minutes, which equals *three hours* of usage.
- An instance is created at 12:03 and is terminated at 12:48. This equals 45 minutes, which equals *one hour* of billed usage.
- An instance is created at 13:43 and is terminated at 14:18. This equals 35 minutes, which equals *one hour* of billed usage, even though the instance lifetime spans two hours.

Comment: That's a bummer, it's makes autoscaling very expensive for a lot of use cases - useful only for long running jobs

Comment: @OferVelich Short-running jobs are more what AWS Lambda or AWS Elastic Container Service are for. Or just keep the instance on and run the jobs on the already-running instance.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address what happens when AWS terminates your spot instance involuntarily.  The final (uually partial) instance-hour in which AWS (not the user, not auto-scaling, not the instance itself) terminates a spot instance is not billed. https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#spot-instances

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the question didn't ask about involuntary termination of spot instances, so it's hardly surprising that the answer doesn't address it.

Comment: @womble, fair point.  Re-reading my comment, it comes across as being critical of the answer, and I really did not intend that. +1. Involuntary termination is always a possibility though, and seemed to me like a noteworthy exception to "rounded up" that bears mentioning in discussion of the cost of spot.